# Add string to default SAS log file name from bash script

Tags: bash, unix, sas, batch-processing

I'm trying to build a simple bash script to automate running some monthly SAS programs at work. The problem I'm running into is that we like to keep logs based on the day a program was run, in case the underlying data changes, but I can't find a way to append the date to the log file.

My base code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

month=`date +%Y%m -d "1 month ago"` #Previous month for log folder
sysdate=`date "+%Y_%m_%d"` #today's date

sasbatdir=/c01/sasdata/public
sasdir=/n04/directory-where-programs-are
saslog=/n04/directory-where-programs-are/Log/$month

cd $sasdir

$sasbatdir/batchsas.sh -s PROGRAM_01.sas -o $saslog -k traditional
$sasbatdir/batchsas.sh -s PROGRAM_02.sas -o $saslog -k traditional
$sasbatdir/batchsas.sh -s PROGRAM_03.sas -o $saslog -k traditional
... etc

exit 0
```

So the above works, but it obviously only outputs log files with the name PROGRAM_01.log, PROGRAM_02.log, etc. format, which get overwritten the next time the script is run in that month.

Things I have tried:

```
$sasbatdir/batchsas.sh -s PROGRAM_01.sas -o $saslog/PROGRAM_01_"$sysdate".log -k traditional
```

and

```
$sasbatdir/batchsas.sh -s PROGRAM_01.sas -log $saslog/PROGRAM_01_"$sysdate".log -k traditional
```

Does not work. `nohup` returns an "Output directory not found" error, and appears to be treating the log name as a directory instead of a file.

```
$sasbatdir/batchsas.sh -s PROGRAM_01.sas -o -t 1 > $saslog/PROGRAM_01_"$sysdate".log -k traditional 2>&1
```

Mostly works, but returns two log files: one with the correct name, but only containing the `nohup` output, and the other with the SAS log, but with both the date (in the wrong format) and the job ID appended. Removing the `2>$1` prevents either from being written. I'd honestly take the second one, if I could figure out how to produce it without the first, though I would prefer to stick to the *Program_Name_YYYY_MM_DD.log* format.

In case it's relevant, the command I'm using to test the programs is `nohup /n04/directory-where-program-is-stored/test_script.sh`

Comment: If the first code above works in the way you describe, it means that the argument after the `-o` tag is the directory where the log is output, not the file name, which seems to be the same as the argument after `-s` where the extension `.sas` is replaced by `.log`. So far my assumptions. But then you introduce other type of arguments: `-t`, `-log`, without explanation. Since we don't have the source of `batchsas.sh`, we don't know what these options are doing and we can't help you further if you don't provide more information about the arguments of `batchsas.sh`

Comment: What is sasbatch.sh ?  Why are you not just calling sas.exe directly?  Is this related to using Grid?

Comment: @Tom sasbatch.sh is an in-house script that I don't have direct access to, but I've been told to point my shell scripts at. It's probably related to using Grid, yeah.
@PierreFrançois `-log` is apparently the operator normally used for this purpose by SAS when called from a command line. I tried it because most of the websites I could find that even vaguely talked about this use it, but it doesn't seem to work with the batchsas script. `-t` similarly is something I came across while hunting around.

Comment: Ah, solved it. Thanks for pointing me at options defined in the sasbatch.sh script; I had been assuming that this was just using already existing operators.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following command:

```
exec > "$saslog/PROGRAM_01_${sysdate}.log" 2>&1
```

It would be preferible to add this command inside the "batchas.sh" script, but in case it is not possible, you can add this line before every "batchas.sh" script call with the new log file.

This command redirects [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout) and [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) to the indicated file, regardless the script was launched from command line, `crontab` or with `nohup`.